# How to get round trip time while calling SOAP webservice using KSOAP in android?

Tags: android, web-services, soap, ksoap2, roundtrip

I am developing an Android application which rely on .NET web service for dynamic data. So, to communicate with SOAP web methods i am using KSOAP2 third party API. It is working fine. but i need to get the round trip time for each web service call using KSOAP2 because my application running slow when compared with same application running in iPhone. So I need to know the RTT to improve the performance of my Android application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the call to .NET service around basic time measuring technique and add the response time in logs for later inspection.  Something like this...

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
<...call to .NET server ...>
System.out.println("Time taken: "+ ((System.currentTimeMillis() - start)) + "ms");
```

Comment: i also trying the same , but don't we have any other way defined by KSOAP2 api?

Comment: This answer is wrong. A RTT is the two-way latency between two endpoints. If you make a call to a .NET server, you will get more than double the RTT because of the TCP connection establishment, then the request, then the response (which could be in many packets). What this measures is (TCP Establishment Time + Application Response Time + TCP Tear Down Time). To measure RTT you need to be able to clock the time between a TCP fragment being sent and it being acknowledged (ACK'd) by the other endpoint, or simply ping that endpoint.